# match NSString against NSString field of an array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, matching

I have an `NSMutableArray` called myObjectArray which contains and array of `NSObjects` called myObject. myObject has two fields (elements?) which are `NSString`'s. like this:

```
@interface myObject : NSObject {
   NSString * string1;
   NSString * string2;
}
```

I have an `NSMutableArray` which contains about 50 of these objects, all with different string1's and string2's. then I have and independent `NSString` variable, called otherString;

Is there a fast way to access the myObject from myObjectArray whose string1 matches otherString?

i should say, this is what i have, but i wonder if there is a faster way:

```
-(void) matchString: {

    NSString * testString = otherString;
    for(int i=0; i<[myObjectArray count];i++){
    myObject * tempobject = [myObjectArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * tempString = tempobject.string1;
        if ([testString isEqualToString:tempString]) {
            // do whatever
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i should say, this is what i have, but i wonder if there is a faster way:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this,

**Using Predicates**

```
NSPredicate * filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"string1 MATCHES[cd] %@", otherString];
NSArray * filteredArray = [myObjectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Now `filteredArray` has all the `myObject` instances that have their `string1` matching `otherString`.

**Using [`indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW21)**

```
NSUInteger index = [myObjectArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(BOOL)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    myObject anObject = obj;
    return [anObject.string1 isEqualToString:otherString];
}
```

If there is an object that satisfies the condition, `index` will point you to its index. Otherwise it will have the value `NSNotFound`.

You can also look at `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` if you want all the objects satisfying the condition.

Comment: well, it looks like it should work, but I'm getting this error::


incompatible block pointer types initializing 'signed char (^)(struct myObject *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)'